# Get value of input in table and then save in mySql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have seen some answers but I have not found anything that I want. I have a table with these rows:

```
while ($rown = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulti)){
    echo "<tr style=text-align:center>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['emri']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['mbiemri']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['dega']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['viti_shkollor']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text style= width:30px />"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

It works perfectly but I want to get the values of input type that user enters and then to put them in a mySql database. Also the table has a submit button as below so when the user completes all of the table inputs then press the submit and all of values go to the database.

```
 <input type="submit" value="prano" name="prano" style="margin:0 auto;" />
```

It is difficult for me to get the value of input and to put it in a variable. I hope you understand my question. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, there are ***plenty*** of tutorials out there on how to do use a database with php / forms.

Comment: why have you not mentioned name in input boxes, without name you cant acess it value in $_POST

Comment: yes i think there is my problem i will fix it and ι wish work

Comment: 1) Never use mysql_* syntax. it is deprecated and also removed in PHP7 2) You have syntax error. **ON your error_reporting** 3) read form attributes and request methods 4) form's **name** attribute is required. that attribute value you will receive in $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few points which you need to include:

1) add form in to your html

2) add name to all input box with in while

```
echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';

while ($rown = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulti)){
    echo "<tr style=text-align:center>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['emri']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['mbiemri']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['dega']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rown['viti_shkollor']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input name='custom[".$rown['id']."]' type=text style= width:30px />"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 

echo "</form>";
```

So that now in test.php:

in `$_POST[custom]` you will get array of values of all input field custom.

Comment: means what you want to perform with $_POST['custom']

Comment: yaa just $data_array = $_POST['custom']; now  $data_array will contain entire array

Comment: foreach($data_array as $arr) { echo $arr; }